# How to specify MBean name in JBoss EAP 6 / JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jmx

In JBoss 5 you were able to use :

```
@Service(objectName = "my.app.name:service=NameThatILike")
@Management(ServiceManagement.class)
```

to name the JMX MBean in the way I like

How to do the same in JBoss AS7 / EAP 6?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you do it in `META-INF/jboss-service.xml` in the SAR. Something like this:

```
<server>
  <mbean code="org.example.HelloService" name="my.app.name:service=NameThatILike">
     <attribute name="Message">Hello!!</attribute>
  </mbean>
</server>
```